# How to synchronize a4j:jsFunction and actionListener in Jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I have following code for execution but it is giving some problem related ajax request.

actionListener Call on Button Click

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" alt="OligoWalk" styleClass="common_button" onclick="createNewLog();showProgressLayer();" oncomplete="parent.document.getElementById('resultFrm').src ='#{MyResearchView.resultToShow}';parent.reRenderLogSection();" actionListener="#{MyResearchView.executeTool}">        <f:attribute name="toolClass" value="com.sequerome.service.impl.tools.Oligowalk" />
<f:attribute name="toolId" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolId}" />   <f:attribute name="toolName" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolName}" />                    <f:attribute name="inputParamFile" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.inputParamFile}" />
<f:attribute name="paramMap" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolParamBean.paramMap}" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

A4j:jsFunction

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="createNewLog"
   actionListener="#{MyResearchView.createNewLogEntry}"
   oncomplete="parent.reRenderLogSection();executeTool();">
   <f:attribute name="toolId" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolId}" />
   <f:attribute name="toolName" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolName}"/></a4j:jsFunction>
```

1. createNewLog() function has to complete first
2. executeTool() function has to complete after that.

Currently it is calling in same way but half of the createNewLog() function execute first then it goes to executeTool() function. Here it take some code for execution and again it moves towards createNewlog() function. After this a createNewLog() get executed then again executeTool() get executed.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" alt="OligoWalk" styleClass="common_button" onclick="createNewLog();showProgressLayer();" oncomplete="parent.document.getElementById('resultFrm').src ='#{MyResearchView.resultToShow}';parent.reRenderLogSection();" actionListener="#{MyResearchView.executeTool}">        <f:attribute name="toolClass" value="com.sequerome.service.impl.tools.Oligowalk" />
<f:attribute name="toolId" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolId}" />   <f:attribute name="toolName" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolName}" />                    <f:attribute name="inputParamFile" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.inputParamFile}" />
<f:attribute name="paramMap" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolParamBean.paramMap}" />
</a4j:commandButton>

<a4j:jsFunction name="createNewLog"
   actionListener="#{MyResearchView.createNewLogEntry}"
   oncomplete="parent.reRenderLogSection();executeTool();">
   <f:attribute name="toolId" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolId}" />
   <f:attribute name="toolName" value="#{ToolCustomeFormView.toolName}"/></a4j:jsFunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your aiming at here. Some code would help. There is an javascript event called oncomplete for the a4j:jsFunction. I guess one approach is to call the other js functions when this event is received...

Comment: The OP didn't format the code, so it was swallowed. I fixed the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms may be a result of a4j:function being an asynchronous function. I believe what is going on behind the scenes is:

- createNewLog();

  - calls a4j:function
  - a4j:function sends a request
  - a4j:function returns (request is still happening)
- showProgressLayer();

  - calls a4j:function
  - a4j:fucntion sends a request (createNewLog request happens to be half way done now)
  - a4j:function returns (request is still happening)
- actionListener request is fired

  - request is executed at server, possibly while createNewLog and showProgressLayer are still running

A solution would be to add [queues](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/queue.jsf) on the client side and [synchronization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) on the server side.